# Hacer varios menus en java

Tags: java

quería saber como puedo realizar tres menus en java. Hasta ahora he realizado 2, sé como realizarlo, pero no sé como hacerlo sin repetir el switch case.

```
do{
            int op = menu();
            switch(op) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:
                seguir = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opcion no válida. Rango admitido: 1-4");
            }
        }while(seguir);

public static int menu() {
        System.out.println("¿Qué opción quiere realizar a continuación?\n"
                + "\n"
                + "#############################################################\n"
                + "1--> Opcion 1.\n"
                + "2--> Opcion 2.\n"
                + "3--> Opcion 3.\n"
                + "4--> Salir del programa.\n"
                + "#############################################################\n");

        int op;
        op =0;
        try{
            op = input.nextInt();
        }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
            System.out.println("No se admiten letras.\nVuelva a intentarlo de nuevo.");
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
        }

        return op;
    }
```

No sé si entendeis a lo que me refiero, lo que quiero es hacer 3 menús, por que cada menú tiene distintas opciones, pero ¿hay alguna forma de que solo tenga un switch -case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // MENU
    imprimirMenu();
    char salir = 's';
    char intro = '\n';

    System.out.print("\n\nIntroduce una opcion: ");
    char opcion = (char) System.in.read();

    while (opcion != salir) {

        char segundoCaracter = (char) System.in.read(); // Deberia ser un intro.
        while (segundoCaracter != intro) {
            opcion = 'z';
            segundoCaracter = (char) System.in.read();
        }
        switch (opcion) {

            case 'a':

                break;

            case 'b':

                break;

            case 'c':

                break;

            case 'd':
                verSubMenu1();
                break;

            case 'e':
                verSubMenu2();
                break;

            case 'f':

                break;

            case 'g':

                break;

            case 'h':
                imprimirMenu();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("La opcion introducida no es correcta.");
                break;
            // salir -----------------------------------> 's'
        }

        System.out.print("Introduce una opcion: ");
        opcion = (char) System.in.read();
    }
    System.out.println("La ejecucion del programa ha finalizado.");
}
```

Comment: ¿Me entiendes por donde voy? No se si lo ves claro. Se hace asi por que el si no el método Main te quedaria muy largo e ininteligible y asi lo acortas y simplemente haces llamadas a los metodos de los submenus.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que no te escapas de hacer un CASE para cada menú, si lo estas haciendo de esa manera. Pero yo por no repetir todos los CASE en el mismo método los separaría en métodos distintos. No se si me entiendes o me explicado suficientemente.

Comment: Entonces para cada uno haria un switch case, pero como lo llamo entre si, por ejemplo el primero lo tengo como lo que puse arriba pero como meto el otro swich case?, En todas las opciones llamo al switch case? (pero estos estarían fuera del main?)

Comment: Exacto, estarian fuera del main todos los menus, para claridad del propio codigo, se llama codigo limpio. Y seria una cosa asi:

Comment: Esto lo pudiste haber puesto en tu misma respuesta. Simplemente editala y ya. No debes agregar otra respuesta si ya hiciste una.